# maps, iterators, and complex structs - STL errors

Tags: c++, stl, debugging, iterator

So, I have two structs:

```
struct coordinate {
    float x;
    float y;
}

struct person {
    int id;
    coordinate location;
}
```

and a function operating on coordinates:

```
float distance(const coordinate& c1, const coordinate& c2);
```

In my main method, I have the following code:

```
map<int,person> people;
// populate people
map<int,map<float,int> > distance_map;
map<int,person>::iterator it1,it2;
for (it1=people.begin(); it1!=people.end(); ++it1) {
    for (it2=people.begin(); it2!=people.end(); ++it2) {
        float d = distance(it1->second.location,it2->second.location);
        distance_map[it1->first][d] = it2->first;
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error upon build:

```
stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of ‘std::iterator_traits<coordinate>’:
stl_iterator_base_types.h:129: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct coordinate’
stl_iterator_base_types.h:130: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct coordinate’
stl_iterator_base_types.h:131: error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct coordinate’
stl_iterator_base_types.h:132: error: no type named ‘pointer’ in ‘struct coordinate’
stl_iterator_base_types.h:133: error: no type named ‘reference’ in ‘struct coordinate’
```

And it blames it on the line:

```
float d = distance(it1->second.location,it2->second.location);
```

Why does the STL complain about my code?

Comment: Possibly irrelevant question: are floats going to work for a key value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a function in the standard library called `std::distance`, which operates on iterators. So it looks like the compiler is trying to call that one instead of yours. I'd remove the `using namespace std;` directive if you're using it, and just say `using std::map;`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you probably have a `using namespace std;` somewhere the compiler confuses your function `float distance(const coordinate& c1, const coordinate& c2)` with the functions from the `algorithm` header.

```
template <class InputIterator>
inline |stl-iterator_traits|<InputIterator>::difference_type
distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

template <class |stl-InputIterator|, class Distance>
void distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Distance& n);
```